# Get Product Quantity in PHTML

Tags: magento-1.9, php

This is current code for short description in default `list.phtml`

```
  <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
```

Now instead of this `short_description` I want  to print `quantity` in list page.

Comment: you mean how many qty available in product right ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Insted of that short description I only want the quantity to be printed.

Comment: please check answer.

Comment: Check my detail answer and let me know if any issue. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to load proudct by cataloginventory model object and get current product quantity by using below code,

**$_product**  is your list page product object.

```
 $stockQty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

 echo $stockQty->getQty();
```

You can debug more info of Quantity/Stock related data using,

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($stockQty->getData());
```

Comment: Sure ! Minimum 8 min required !

Answer (score 2):

**Get stock information of the loaded product**

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
```

**You can check stock data in this way:-**

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($stock->getData()); echo "</pre>";
```

**Or, you can print individually like this:-**

```
echo $stock->getQty();
echo $stock->getMinQty();
echo $stock->getMinSaleQty();
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.